# Missing Sender Class for J2ME SMS MIDlet

Tags: java, java-me

this is my first time being on one of these and I am trying to figure out why when using a sender class to declare a sender, I get an error from Wireless Tool Kit telling me that it doesn't work. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? In case it looks familiar, it is the same code from the example in the Apress Beginning J2ME 3rd Edition textbook.

```
private Sender mSender = null;
mSender = Sender.getInstance();
```